# Rename/Delete specific amount of characters of nested Foldernames

Tags: loops, batch-file, rename

folder layout is like:

- root\folder1a\subfolder2a\randommmsubfolder3a
- root\folder1b\subfolder2b\randommmsubfolder3b
- root\folder1c\subfolder2c\randommmsubfolder3c

i want to delete/strip the 8 characters  of the folder names in the third level deep. basically the "randommm" part of each name. some names have exclamation marks in it.
i have a loop batch but it only renames the first encounter, but does not progress anything after. here is my code:

```
cd "C:\Root"
for /D %%i in (*) do (
cd %%i
for /D %%j in (*) do (
cd %%j
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /D %%k in (*) do (
set name=%%k
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
ren "!name!" "!name:~8!"
endlocal
endlocal
)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
pushd "%sourcedir%"
for /D %%i in (*) do (
 pushd "%%i"
  for /D %%j in (*) do (
  pushd "%%j"
  setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
  for /D %%k in (*) do (
   set "name=%%k"
   setlocal enableextensions ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
   ECHO ren "!name!" "!name:~8!"
   ENDLOCAL
  )
  ENDLOCAL
  popd 
 )
 popd
)
popd

GOTO :EOF
```

Two problems - the second `endlocal` needs to be moved so it matches the nesting level of the corresponding `setlocal` and `cd` changes directory, but those directory changes are **not** backed out by an `endlocal` AFAII. Using `pushd/popd` ensures correct progression.

Comment: `endlocal` does restore the previous working directory, because the corresponding `setlocal` creates a new environment, which includes variables and working directories; even the current directory of every drive is recalled...

Comment: @aschipfl : Ah, good. I'll make a note of that (but probably forget it by the time it comes up next)

Comment: @Magoo the solution worked for me. finally learned how to make use of pushd and popd, thanks a lot